# toggle class of element and add new element in view with old class

Tags: javascript, jquery, push, element

I'm working at a comment system for a website.
I am using jquery to update the view after comment under post is posted.

The element I am pushing the comment after post is like this:

```
<p class="card-text new_comment_{{$i->id}}" style="display:none"></p>
```

So what I do is

```
//Manages post in view
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("submit", ".dynamic-form", function (e) {

            var form_id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            //removes the 'post_' part from id
            var id = this.id.replace('post_', '');
            var new_comment_class = '.new_comment_' + id;
            var new_comment_class_removal = 'new_comment_' + id;
            var comments_id = '#comments_' + id;
            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    var resultStr = "";

                    resultStr = resultStr + "<a href=\"#\">" + data.user_name + " <\/a>" + data.body ;


                    $(comments_id).find(new_comment_class).html(resultStr).slideToggle(150).promise().done(function () {
                        $(new_comment_class).fadeIn("fast").toggleClass(new_comment_class_removal);
                    });

                    $(form_id).slideToggle(150).promise().done(function () {
                        $(form_id).fadeOut("fast");
                    });

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

so after the javascript gets executed the element loses the class that permits me to find it in the view so that if the user posts again the body of the post doesn't get appended to that element. But now how do I put a new target element as the original one just above the newly creatded one? like this:

```
<p class="card-text new_comment_{{$i->id}}" style="display:none"></p>
<p class="card-text">This is the body of the comment</p>
```

Comment: Why use a unique class and not an id?

Comment: The problem wouldn't change, I would have to remove the id from the original element and create a new element with the old id `<p id="new_comment_{{$i->id}}" class="card-text" style="display:none"></p><p class="card-text">This is the body of the comment</p>`

Comment: solved using http://api.jquery.com/before/

Answer (score 0):

solved using http://api.jquery.com/before/ and some temp variables